# Jhipster : change the email settings dynamically

Tags: java, jhipster

I want to replace the mail settings values from application-dev.hml properties file with my own values.
I do :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "ssl0.ovh.net");
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "myOwnLogin@myApp.fr");
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", "xxx");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);
MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
message.setFrom("myOwnLogin@myApp.fr");
```

But when I receive the mail in my mail box. It's still coming from the adress set in the properties file (userLogin@gmail.com):

> ```
> mail:
>     host: smtp.gmail.com
>     port: 587
>     username: userLogin@gmail.com
>     password: xxxxxx
>     protocol: smtp
>     properties.mail.smtp:
>         auth: true
>         starttls.enable: true
> ```

How can I dynamically change the mail settings in the Java code?

Thanks.

***UPDATE:***

```
javaMailSender.setUsername("userLogin@gmail.com");
javaMailSender.setPassword("xxxxxx");
javaMailSender.setHost("ssl0.ovh.net");
javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
javaMailSender.setPort(25);

MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myOwnLogin@myApp.fr"));
```

Weird, I need to reset javaMailSender properties with any working value (here same values as in the properties file), then I can set the "From" value. This is quite ugly but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
mimeMessage.saveChanges(); // add this line here
```

Comment: still the same issue. it doesn't take the email adress set to mimeMessage.setFrom(..).

Comment: it's working then it's good strange change ,u can give a try to save changes with old code .

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work. do you know how I can access the properties file(application-dev.yml) value from Java? I don't want to set the password directly in the java code.

Comment: i haven't seen anything like that , maybe there could be a indirect way though what you have done is one way yet. you can update your question or post a new question with a more broader tags like java ee etc along with current one

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class EmailConfig {
@Autowired
ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

@Bean
@Qualifier("primaryMailSender")
@Primary
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);

    mailSender.setUsername(applicationProperties.PrimaryEmailConfig().getUsername());
    mailSender.setPassword(applicationProperties.PrimaryEmailConfig().getPassword());

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("secondaryMailSender")
public JavaMailSender getSecondaryJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);

    mailSender.setUsername(applicationProperties.getSecondaryEmailConfig().getUsername());
    mailSender.setPassword(applicationProperties.getSecondaryEmailConfig().getPassword());

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
}
}

// in MailService.java inject the configs above by adding them as constructor parameters:
private final JavaMailSender secondaryJavaMailSender;
private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

public MailService(@Qualifier("primaryMailSender") JavaMailSender javaMailSender
@Qualifier("secondaryMailSender") JavaMailSender secondaryJavaMailSender) {
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    this.secondaryJavaMailSender = secondaryJavaMailSender;
}
```